# Array not receiving radio buttons value

Tags: java, arrays, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem at the moment, not sure why it does this but I am using radio buttons for the user to select how many times they want the loop to run.

So the problem is when I run it, the random numbers are not being stored into the array I get a bounds exception:

Here;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

---

```
public class SortingProgramView extends FrameView {
    int numOfEntries;
    int[] numbers = new int[0];

    private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfEntries-1 ; i++)
   {
    numbers[i]= (-10000) + (int)(Math.random()*20001);
   }
   unsortedInfo();
}
private void unsortedInfo(){
    unsortedOutput.setText(" ");
    for (int j=0;j<=numOfEntries;j++){
        unsortedOutput.append(+numbers[j]+"\n");
    }
}
private void tenEntriesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    numOfEntries = 10;
    numbers = new int[numOfEntries];
}

private void hundredEntriesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    numOfEntries = 100;
    numbers = new int[numOfEntries];
}

private void thousandEntriesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   numOfEntries = 1000;
   numbers = new int[numOfEntries];
}

private void fiveThousandEntriesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    numOfEntries = 5000;
    numbers = new int[numOfEntries];
}
}
```

Comment: You're declaring your array before know how many elements you might need. Wait until the user makes a selection or you actually need the array before initialising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int[] numbers = new int[numOfEntries];
```

Happens before any of these calls:  `tenEntriesActionPerformed`, `hundredEntriesActionPerformed`, etc.

You should change these methods to something like:

```
private void tenEntriesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    numOfEntries = 10;
    numbers = new int[numOfEntries];//resize the array
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It worked, but I got this now:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Comment: At what line do you get this?  It seems you are just going out of the range of the array.  Say the array is size 10, it only has indexes from 0 to 9 (not 10!).

Comment: Can you post your updated code in the opening question?  It shouldn't do that from the code you're displaying

Comment: Your loop in the method `unsortedInfo` is wrong.  Look at the other loop you use and see if you can find what's wrong.  Hint:  you're off my by 1.  :)